# How to solve 'don't import implementation files from another package' warning in generated plugin registrant?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting the following warning message when I try to build my Flutter plugin:

> Don't import implementation files from another package.

I have tried to solve the problem by importing the `package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus_web.dart` and `package:share_plus/share_plus_web.dart` file instead, but this does not seem to work.

The code that is causing the error is:

```
//
// Generated file. Do not edit.
//

// ignore_for_file: directives_ordering
// ignore_for_file: lines_longer_than_80_chars
// ignore_for_file: depend_on_referenced_packages

import 'package:device_info_plus/src/device_info_plus_web.dart';
import 'package:share_plus/src/share_plus_web.dart';


import 'package:flutter_web_plugins/flutter_web_plugins.dart';

// ignore: public_member_api_docs
void registerPlugins(Registrar registrar) {
  DeviceInfoPlusWebPlugin.registerWith(registrar);
  SharePlusWebPlugin.registerWith(registrar);
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you are importing the wrong files. You need to add this to your file and remove the old one.

```dart
import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';
import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';
```

Comment: I tried this too , but did not work .  DeviceInfoPlusWebPlugin , SharePlusWebPlugin becomes undefine and import becomes unused when I use this. I also use DeviceInfoPlusPlugin , SharePlusPlugin but it is Undefined name 'DeviceInfoPlusPlugin'. -Hedwin Coursimault

Comment: Can you provide your pubspec.yaml and pubspec.lock file please ?

Comment: ```Pubspec.yaml dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
share_plus: 
device_info_plus:
```

Comment: ```pubspec.lock
 device_info_plus:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: device_info_plus
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "8.2.2"
  device_info_plus_platform_interface:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: device_info_plus_platform_interface
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "7.0.0"```

Comment: ```pubspec.lock
share_plus:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: share_plus
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "6.3.4"
  share_plus_platform_interface:
    dependency: transitive
    description:
      name: share_plus_platform_interface
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "3.2.1"
```

Comment: These are the file @Hedwin